# Reworking table with data and dates in columns to data and dates in rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, pivot, bigdata

I have multiple files with quantity of product on a given day, but the date is provided in separate columns rather than in rows.

| Product | 01.01.2021 | 02.01.2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product 1 | 10 | 11 |
| product 2 | 11 | 12 |

These are monthly files (30/31 columns), with 186k products and 2 years of data in total, thus reworking such file in Excel is a difficult task.

What I'd like to get is:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product 1 | 01.01.2021 | 10 |
| product 1 | 02.01.2021 | 11 |
| product 2 | 01.01.2021 | 11 |
| product 2 | 02.01.2021 | 12 |

Is there a method to quickly rework such files either in excel or SQL? I'm running out of ideas.

I tried cartesian multiplication and cross joins, but couldn't figure out the way to handle dates in columns' names and quantity in rows. I'd like to move both date and quantity to separate column.

The # of total rows of reworked table would be at least 5,500,000.

Comment: read about unpivot + dynamic sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data reflects this simple example- you can use a dynamic SQL query to create the Unpivot() statement. Given your example data:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable ([Product] nvarchar(50), [01.01.2001] int, [02.01.2021] int);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (N'product 1', 10, 11), (N'product 2', 11, 12);
```

The unpivot for this simple example looks like:

```
  SELECT unpvt.[Product], unpvt.[Date], unpvt.[Quantity] 
  FROM (SELECT  [Product], [01.01.2001], [02.01.2021] 
  FROM [myTable]) AS p 
  UNPIVOT ([Quantity] FOR [Date] IN ( [01.01.2001], [02.01.2021])) AS unpvt
  ORDER BY unpvt.[Product], unpvt.[Date];
```

And the dynamic string that can produce the unpivot code above looks like:

```
--Declare your tableName, unGrouping column and new column names:
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(100) = N'myTable'
DECLARE @unGroupCol nvarchar(100) = N'Product'
DECLARE @newUnPivColsName nvarchar(100) = N'Date'
DECLARE @newUnAggColsName nvarchar(100) = N'Quantity'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) 
 = CONCAT(N'
SELECT unpvt.[', @unGroupCol, '], [', @newUnPivColsName, '] = CAST(unpvt.[', @newUnPivColsName, '] as date), unpvt.[', @newUnAggColsName, 

  '] FROM (SELECT '
 , STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', [', COLUMN_NAME, ']') 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName
       AND (COLUMN_NAME = @unGroupCol  --the Product column in this case
            OR
            COLUMN_NAME LIKE '__.__.____' --the format of the various date columns
           )
         
    --ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION  
    FOR XML PATH ('')   
    ), 1, 1, '') 

 ,        ' FROM [', @tableName,  
       ']) AS p UNPIVOT ([' , @newUnAggColsName,'] FOR [', @newUnPivColsName, '] IN ('

 , STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', [', COLUMN_NAME, ']') 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName
       AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '__.__.____' --the format of the various date columns
       AND COLUMN_NAME <> @unGroupCol --exclude the [Product] column
    --ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION  
    FOR XML PATH ('')   
    ), 1, 1, '') 
 , ')) AS unpvt ORDER BY [', @unGroupCol, '], [', @newUnPivColsName, '];')

EXEC (@sql);
```

This requires specifying the table name, ungroup column, new unpivot column name, and new de-aggregation column name.

Column names from the original source data are acquired from INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS.  In the dynamic code I also casted the original date column names to the date datatype.  The source date columns were identified using the regex pattern `'__.__.____'`, since that reflects the sample data.

Comment: After some adjustments it worked perfectly, thank you very much for the help! Have a blessed day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerQuery to unpivot the data:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivot" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Product"}, "Date", "Quantity")
in
    #"Unpivot"
```

You will have to replace "Tabelle1" with your tables name.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Will it work if the output table has 1 000 000+ rows?

Comment: In theory yes - but I have no experience with real life data. Did you check UNPIVOT for SQL-Server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: you can always split it per product or year or something else, but 1 M rows is nothing really

Comment: Works great for smaller tables, but unfortunately I wasn't able to copy the results to excel - due to the amount of rows. Nevertheless I will definitely use it in the future, same with UNPIVOT syntax. Cheers! :)